# Are "The Carnival of the Animals" and "Danse Macabre" the same piece?

Tags: orchestra

I wonder if "The Carnival of the Animals" and "Danse Macabre" are the same piece? Why are they named differently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 12th movement of the suite "The Carnival of the Animals", Fossils, is copied partly from the "Danse Macabre", a piece previously written by Saint-Saëns.

It quotes the theme of Dance Macabre in a humorous way, and also several other tunes including "Au Clair de la Lune" and "Ah! Vous d'irai-je, Maman" (the tune  English-speakers know as "Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star" or  "The ABC Song").

Comment: Is "Fossils" then a pun on reusing all those old tunes?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis It's a joke, but not a pun.